# In UK politics, is there a metonym for the National Assembly for Wales (like Westminster, Holyrood, Stormont)?

Tags: metonyms

The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland has a national parliament with an internationally used metonym *Westminster* after the *City of Westminster*, London, where the parliament is located (or perhaps after the *Palace of Westminster*, which is in turn named after the *City of Westminster*).

The devolved parliament for Scotland is often referred to as *Holyrood* after the Edinburgh area of Holyrood ([*Brexit talks divide opinion between Holyrood and Westminster*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-37924795))

The Northern Ireland assembly is often called *Stormont* after the *Stormont estate* ([*Stormont failure over gay pardons 'a disgrace'*](http://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/stormont-failure-over-gay-pardons-a-disgrace-35168076.html)).

The National Assembly for Wales is located in a building called the *Senedd* in Cardiff.  I'm not sure what the neighbourhood of Cardiff is called.

The word *senedd* is simply [Welsh for senate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/senedd) and therefore not a metonym.  Is the word *Senedd* word used for the National Assembly for Wales?  Is there any metonym in use?  If so, which one?

Searching far *senedd* at `site:news.bbc.co.uk` yields very few results, and a large fraction are about *the senedd building* rather than about the assembly as an institution.

Comment: http://politicsmadepublic.com/holyrood-cardiff-bay-and-stormont-breaking-down-britains-devolved-governments/ uses Cardiff Bay (the area of Cardiff that the Senedd is located) in a similar manner to Stormont and Holyrood. As does this Guardian article: https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/may/09/scottish-parliament-northern-ireland-welsh-assembly-election-results-diversity

Comment: @JonLarby Interesting, never seen it used like that.  I wonder if a regular British native speaker would understand it with less context.

Comment: The Welsh sided with the English when they voted against independence, and again when they voted to leave the EU, so in practice journalists don't have many reasons to report on what the National Assembly for Wales does (or *wants* to do). This is completely different to Holyrood, which is in *constant* conflict with Westminster, and Stormont (which many English would be glad to hand over to Eire, and wash their hands of the whole sorry mess).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Off-topic question: What vote are you referring to with *The Welsh voted against independence*?

Comment: @gerrit - Possibly not. Imagine a BBC news report that begins "The atmosphere at Stormont this evening is tense..." - most people would understand the context. "The atmosphere at Cardiff Bay this evening is tense..." would probably only be understood later, as more context was added. It's a useful metonym though, and one that is arguably needed, so may grow in usage in the future.

Comment: [Welsh devolution referendum, 1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_devolution_referendum,_1979) - where plans for devolution intended to lead to independence were defeated by a majority of 4:1. They have an Assembly now, but I'm sure no significant fraction of the population actually want full independence (unlike the Scots, they understand basic economic realities! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see any mention of independence there but let's not get into an off-topic political discussion here.

Comment: @gerrit: It's not *entirely* off topic, since the fact that collectively the Welsh didn't and don't seek independence means there's not much reason to refer to their Assembly as a (political) "agent". That Assembly does have powers (though less than Holyrood), but it doesn't really act as a coherent entity anyway, so from the media's perspective it doesn't particularly merit its own epithet (*yet*, at least! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've managed to dis or belittle the populations or institutions of 3 of the 4 nations of the UK in this thread. Do you think you could tone it down a touch under the SE admonition of 'be nice'? Thanks

Comment: @Spagirl: I actually *like* the Scots, Northern Irish, and Welsh. It just so happens that *collectively* the first two groups are often in political contention with the UK parliament, so newspapers (the only likely source of the metonym OP seeks here) often need a pithy sobriquet to reference them. They rarely have occasion to write about collecftive decisions taken in Cardiff that are in opposition to Westminster, which I'm saying is probably at least part of the reason why they've never promoted any particular term here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers At the risk of putting in my two-penneth here, I recall numerous occasions when Conservative ministers and members have said insulting things about the Labour-controlled Welsh Assembly, particularly as regards to the cost and supposed inefficiencies of the National Health Service in Wales. I have even heard it suggested that some Welsh residents travel to England for treatment. I doubt the argument, but there certainly isn't much love lost between Cardiff Bay and Conservative HQ.

Comment: No, no. I know the city and the locale. I have neither read nor heard any one refer to the Assembly building as Cardiff Bay in the way that the Houses of Parliament in London have been dubbed Westminster (the building itself is the Palace of Westminster though this nomenclature is  seldom used in the popular media or in speech). The forerunner of Cardiff Bay (parts thereof) was Tiger Bay, the Cardiff docklands that had a certain reputation and gave us the movie Tiger Bay, Joe Erskine (boxer) and the wonderful singer-entertainer, Dame Shirley Bassey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a commonly used one of the same sort, no. Cardiff would probably be used if need be. It wouldn't quite fit the same pattern, since it is the whole city - the Senedd is right on Cardiff Bay, so that might work but I'm not sure I've seen that in the wild. There's no need for it to fit the same pattern of course: for most places in the world we refer to the city itself rather than an estate or neighbourhood.

There's also the fact that for cultural, historical and legal reasons the Senedd is less of a focus in Wales than the Scottish or Northern Irish parliaments are in their countries. That is also why it is called an assembly and not a parliament, and that might be why it doesn't come up as often enough for such a metonym to have taken hold.

Comment: I have a suggestion: Paper Tiger Bay